# Stuck: while deploying nestjs app on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nestjs

Deploy status failed and got this error in logs file.
I have created the .npmrc file and write unsafe-perm=true
is there anyone who can help me?

node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@5.0.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@5.0.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-11-19T07_14_24_912Z-debug.log

Comment: i have resolved this issue by uninstalling bcrypt and puppeteer lib. i think some lib is not compatible with the ubuntu environment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.